# {{#each objects}} vs. {{#each model.objects}} vs. {{#each content.objects}}

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I wrote a very simple route that exports an object with a sub-collection as its model:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.Object.create({
            objects: [...]
        });
    }
});
```

Now in my template I try iterating over the objects like so:

```
{{#each objects}}
    ...
{{/each}}
```

For some reason this works in the official ember jsfiddle, but when I run the same code locally, I have to change it to {{#each content.objects}} to make it work. The only differences I spot between my case and the jsfiddle are:

1. I use browserify + hbsify to compile the template, and am not using inline handlebars templates
2. I don't define an application template, while the jsfiddle does.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can explain the differences between the 3, and hopefully that will clear things up a bit.

- `{{#each objects}}` - This pulls from the `objects` property on the controller. If you've explicitly defined a property named `objects`, it will use that. But if you haven't explicitly defined one, which I assume is the case, the controller (which extends from [ObjectProxy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ObjectProxy.html)), will proxy the request to the `content` property.

  So first Ember calls `controller.get('objects')`, which will return `undefined` since you didn't define an `objects` property. From there, the `unknownProperty` function will be called, which will return the content of `content.objects` instead.

  Bottom line, using this form will differ depending on how your controller is declared. Try to avoid this one if possible.
- `{{#each model.objects}}` - `model` is actually an alias for `content` but you're not technically supposed to know that. The `content` property is merely an implementation detail of how Ember object proxies work.

  In the end, just know that `model` holds your current model, and you should prefer this method of accessing properties. (Because in my opinion, it eliminates ambiguity.)
- `{{#each content.objects}}` - `content` is an implementation detail of Ember's object proxies. In this particular case, `content` is the model that you supplied. You should avoid using this method, as it relies on the property of the object proxy to be named `content` (which could technically change at any time).

So for your problem, I imagine that `{{#each objects}}` isn't working because there is another `objects` property defined somehow. You should use `{{#each model.objects}}` instead. (Or, if you can, switch to an [ArrayController](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/) and just use `{{#each}}`.

Comment: nice explaination. Could you guide me where you found all these details.

Comment: The [ObjectProxy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ObjectProxy.html) documentation and source code is where you'll find most of it. For the most part, this is just one of those things that you learn when you have issues with it (like John P does now.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The issue seems to be the way I precompiled my .hbs templates. When I switched to producing plain javascript files without amd modules, the problem was fixed and I can use all three ways without an issue.